# $\phi, \psi$ homeomorphisms on $U, V$ $\implies$ $\phi(U\cap V) \cong \psi(U\cap V)$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $U,V \subset M$ be open subsets in some manifold $M$. Let $\phi, \psi$ be homeomorphisms on $U, V$ respectively. Is it true that we then have $\phi(U\cap V) \cong \psi(U\cap V)$?

Comment: And $U, V$ are?

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: homeomorphisms between which spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $U, V$ are open, $U\cap V$ is also open, and so is $\varphi(U\cap V)$ inside $\varphi(U)$. It's easy to see the open sets in $U\cap V$ correspond exactly to the open sets in the image $\varphi(U\cap V)$, which means $\varphi{\upharpoonright}_{U\cap V}$ is a homeomorphism. Similarly for $\psi$, hence
$$\varphi(U\cap V)\cong U\cap V\cong\psi(U\cap V).$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is true, since $$\phi(U\cap V)\cong U\cap V\cong\psi(U\cap V).$$

Each one of the equivalences follows from the fact that the restriction of a homeomorphism to a subspace is again a homeomorphism.